# Swift webView dissapears from screen

Tags: swift, webview, view, uiview, uiwebview

When I run my app on simulator, everything is shown perfect, both webView and view below it.
But after a second webView disappears from screen. I don't know if I make a mistake with constraints.Here is how my screen should look like : 
  [image]

Consraints: 
[image]

And this is simulator 1 second after it has been loaded: 
 [image]

Comment: is your link in webview is working right ?